# Dualizing complex description in Stacks project

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-categories, derived-functors, cohen-macaulay-rings

The question is closely related to this one [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3587200/dualizing-complex-of-cohen-macaylay-variety) (more precisely the reference the comment by AGl earner) and is aimed to understand the proof of Lemma 20.2 from notes from Stacks [notes from Stacks](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/download/dualizing.pdf) on dualizing complex. Lemma 20.2 states

> **Lemma 20.2**. Let $(A,m, \kappa=A/m)$ be a Noetherian local ring with normalized dualizing
>   complex $\omega^{\bullet}_A$
>   and dualizing module $\omega_A:= H^{- \dim A}\omega^{\bullet}_A$. The following are equivalent:
>
> (1) $A$ is Cohen-Macaulay,
>
> (2) $\omega^{\bullet}_A$ is concentrated in a single degree, and
>
> (3) $\omega^{\bullet}_A= \omega_A[\dim(A)]$. (i.e. a complex that is concentrated in degree $\dim(A)$ and is zero in other degrees)

In this case $\omega$ is a maximal Cohen-Macaulay module. The Proof refers to *Lemma 16.7*:

> **Lemma 16.7.**
>   Let  $(A,m, \kappa=A/m)$ be a Noetherian local ring with normalized dualizing complex $\omega^{\bullet}_A$. Let $M$ be a finite $A$-module. Here $M$ is considered as complex (or a class of this complex in $D(A)$) with $M[0]=M$ and $M[i]=0$ for $i \neq 0$. The following are equivalent
>
> (1) $M$ is Cohen-Macaulay,
>
> (2) $Ext^i _A(M,\omega^{\bullet}_A)$  is nonzero for a single $i$,
>
> (3) $Ext^{-i} _A(M,\omega^{\bullet}_A)$
>    is zero for $i \neq \dim(Supp(M))$.

I not understand why 16.7 imply the $(1) \Rightarrow (3)$ in 20.2: why does it imply that $\omega^{\bullet}_A= \omega_A[\dim(A)]$? I guess that we apply 16.7 with $M=A$.

Then by definition for two complexes $X^{\bullet}, Y^{\bullet}$ Ext is defined by

$$Ext_A ^i(X^{\bullet}, Y^{\bullet}):= Hom_{D(A)}(X^{\bullet}, Y^{\bullet}[i])= Hom_{D(A)}(X^{\bullet}[-i], Y^{\bullet})$$

Moreover $Ext_A ^i(X^{\bullet}, Y^{\bullet})= H^i (RHom_{D(A)}(X^{\bullet}, Y^{\bullet}))$. If $Y^{\bullet} \to I^{\bullet}$ is an injective resolution, then we can calculate it by $Ext_A ^i(X^{\bullet}, Y^{\bullet})=Hom_{K(A)}(X^{\bullet}, I^{\bullet}[i])$ and similary with aprojective resolution of $X^{\bullet}$.

$A$ has most natural projective resolution $I^{\bullet} _A \to A$  by $... \to 0 \to A \xrightarrow{\text{id}} A $.

thus we obtain $Ext^i _A(A,\omega^{\bullet}_A) = Hom_{D(A)}(A,\omega^{\bullet}_A[i])= Hom_{K(A)}(I^{\bullet} _A, \omega^{\bullet}_A[i])=Hom_A(A, \omega^{\bullet}_A[i]_0)= (\omega^{\bullet}_A)_i$.

now comes the part which I not understand:
Why $\omega^{\bullet}_{-d}= H^{-d}(\omega^{\bullet}) = 
\omega_A[d]_{-d}= \omega_A$ (recall definition of 
$\omega_A$ above)?

Since we have observed that $Ext^i _A(A,\omega^{\bullet}_A) =
\omega^{\bullet}_i$ we have "only" to show that 
$Ext^{-d} _A(A,\omega^{\bullet}_A)= H^{-d}(\omega^{\bullet})$.

Why is it true?

If we continue as before then $Ext^{-d} _A(A,\omega^{\bullet}_A)
= H^{-d}(Hom_{D(A)}(A, \omega^{\bullet}_A)=
H^{-d}(Hom_A(A, \omega^{\bullet}_A)= 
= H^{-d}( \omega^{\bullet}_0)= \omega^{\bullet}_0$. This is nonsense.